# How to Navigate to a particular category index number in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a page/screen **CountryNameScreen** this screen has list of countries like this.

```
var countries = [
      'Australia',
      'NewZeland',
      'United State',
      'Russia',
      'United Kingdom',
      'India',
    ];
```

There is an **onTap** function for the above countries. When we **click** on the country the detailed information page displayed on screen.

**The problem is this**: i want to navigate from other page of this app
to navigate to "United State" which is on index 2

```
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    CupertinoPageRoute(
                      builder: ((context) =>
                          const CountryNameScreen()),
                    ),
                  );
                },
```

What should i write while adding navigation code.

Comment: so for United State you want to navigate to another page rather than all countries common your current  detailed information page navigation ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code I have try your Expected Result, when you click country name it jumps to selected country name page.

**Your country List:**

```
 var countries = [
    'Australia',
    'NewZeland',
    'United State',
    'Russia',
    'United Kingdom',
    'India',
  ];
```

Your List Display Widget:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: countries.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => CountryNameScreen(
              countryName: countries[index].toString(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      title: Text(
        countries[index].toString(),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

**CountryNameScreen Widget:**

```
class CountryNameScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CountryNameScreen({required this.countryName});
  final String countryName;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(countryName),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Selected Country - $countryName',
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Full Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  var countries = [
    'Australia',
    'NewZeland',
    'United State',
    'Russia',
    'United Kingdom',
    'India',
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: countries.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              CupertinoPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => CountryNameScreen(
                  countryName: countries[index].toString(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          title: Text(
            countries[index].toString(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CountryNameScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CountryNameScreen({required this.countryName});
  final String countryName;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(countryName),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Selected Country - $countryName',
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Country Name Result -> [image: image1]

Select Australia Country Result- [image: image2]

Select United State Country Result-[image]

[image: image4]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty poorly explained. Please try to add more details or explanation.

If you mean you want to dynamically go to a country page, try to add some constructor argument like this:
CountryNameScreen(countryName: indexNumber)

And with a variable (for ex: indexNumber) on top of the build method set the the indexNumber value to the value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to send an index so the screen be able to show you a country name
EX: For new york the index 2

Inside the CountryNameScreen, you need to add a property for this index
And then to add the property into class' constructor

```dart
const CountryNameScreen({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

final int index;
```

Then, from the place you want to navigate to this screen, you can do it by passing the variable like this:

```dart
                  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    CupertinoPageRoute(
                      builder: ((context) {
                        return CountryNameScreen(
                            index: 2, //country's index
                          );
                      }),
                    ),
                  )
```

In case that you want to show the countries in a list and to get the country dynamically, you can use the following code and you can edit the inner widget as you like

```dart
ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    CupertinoPageRoute(
                      builder: ((context) {
                        return CountryNameScreen(
                            index: index,
                          );
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      countries[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            separatorBuilder: (context, _) => const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
            itemCount: countries.length)
```

Hope it helps